# How to put outline for a gridview(or table view) boxes in android

Tags: android, uitableview, gridview

In my application I want a 5x5 grid view(or table view). I do not want to use image view or text view in side the grid view(or table view).

1. I just want to put out lines for the cells in side that grid view.
   Is it possible and how can I do it?
2. I also want to take identity of individual cells inside the grid
   view (or table view)?

[image]

This is grid view and I used  image views to make cells visible to users. But with out using this images or any text views I want to display cells.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: There are many ways to trick it for outlining the boxes or whole grid. Please provide a simple image to support your requirement.

Comment: But I do not want to place any image or text view over it. But cells should be visible to user

Comment: In that case I will suggest use two layouts. One is your background with some color (red, green, blue,black..etc) then upon that add one more layout with some margin(How much border size you want). So it will give you an effect of border. This is one of the trick I was talking about earlier.

Comment: By this technique I can get the border around the layout but not around individual cell in side the view.

Comment: thej, please provide a simple image to support your question. I'hv already asked for an image that will narrate more clear picture about your doubt/requirement. Anyways if it can show you a border for a layout. Why can not you use the same for all of your cell??

Comment: I have edited the question with image. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: It's just the design methodology. Use it for how to proceed.]

Use these as guide to your code [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html), [GridView Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use a square xml `drawable` as background with stroke set to width and color of your choice, fill color set to transparent and may be rounded corners for extra fancy.